# Roboust Network connectivity

Tags: networking, wireless, dhcp, hostapd, wpa-supplicant

I want to run a headless (no monitor and keyboard) Pi 3a in the somewhat fluent environment (at home, in an Artist’s studio, on the attic of an cathedral). The Pi is controlling some Christmas displays via DMX.

I want always be able to connect to the Pi via local WiFi/ssh for administration. I also want the Pi to connect to loco we see when possible.

So my goal book at somethings like:

1. Run an AP on the with 10.0.0.1 as the Adress. DHCP service for 10.0.0.0/24 Would be a nice bonus.
2. Also connect the build-in WiFi  as a client to a known AP (if available).

this seems to be unusual combination. Although to me it looks highly desirable in all headless IoT scenarios.

Any suggestions on how to approach this?

Comment: I understood some chipsets can run at the same time in client and in AP mode. But maybe I was mistaken or the Pi chipset is not one of them. ` iw list` says `interface combinations are not supported` - so you are right, I will need an additional dongle. interference should be not an big issue when using a different channel.

Comment: @goldilocks Your comment is not correct. It is possible to run an AP **and** a client uplink only on the one available built-in wifi-device using a virtual interface **ap0** associated to **wlan0** (see my answer).

Comment: That makes sense; I have not used a virtual interface that way.  All apologies (comment deleted).

Answer (score 4):

With the built-in wifi-device of a Raspberry Pi it is possible to create an access point together with an uplink client connection. This can be done with creating a virtual interface **ap0** (or what name do you like) from the physical interface **wlan0**. Because the virtual interface **ap0** depends on **wlan0** it is a bit sophisticated to manage its initialization in the correct order. But how to do it you can have a look at
[Access point as WiFi router/repeater, optional with bridge](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/89804/79866)

Answer (score 0):

This would seem to be much more feasible with a second pi. Perhaps just an additional microcontroller to distribute the tasks that can't adequately be serviced by a single pi.